# Angular return observable from eventListener

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have method in angular app service which should return img blob data

```
getPlanImage$(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get$(`${this.serviceUrl}/Photo`, 'blob' )
    .pipe(map((response:any) => {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
        return reader.result;
      }, false);
      if (response) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(response);
     }
    }))
  }
```

and I am subscribing to it like this :

```
this.assetService.getPlanImage$().subscribe(data => {
      this.imageToShow = data;
    })
```

I can see sucessfull call to image service in chrome network, but this method in this line `this.imageToShow = data;` data is undefined

Comment: your map does not return anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do something like below.

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { flatMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
...


getPlanImage$(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get$(`${this.serviceUrl}/Photo`, 'blob').pipe(
        flatMap((response: any) => {
            let reader = new FileReader();

            if (response) {
                reader.readAsDataURL(response);
            }

            return fromEvent(reader, 'load').pipe(map(() => reader.result));

        })
    );
}
```